Powers of an interesting matrix
In a discussion about a matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0 \end{bmatrix},$$
$A^{49}$, $A^{98}$ are told  to be $A$ and $I$, respectively. I checked that the former is right but the latter is false. Further, numerical, experiments yielded that
$A^{3k-2}=A$ and $A^{3k}=I,\cdots(*)$
where $k$ is a positive integer. These, two results can be understood by noticing that $A^3=I$ and $A^{-2}=A$.
The question is: Are there some more generalizations akin to these for $A$ and what could be other proofs for (*)?

$A$ is the permutation matrix of the cyclic permutation $\sigma:=(1; 3; 2)$, hence $A^k$ is the permutation matrix of $\sigma^k$. In particular, if $k=3n$, $\sigma^k=\text{Id}$, and $A^k$ is the permutation matrix of the identity, hence $I_3$.

You want generalisations for permutation matrices or for matrices exponent or generalisation of computation of polynomial of your matrix?

Also another proof would be $\chi_A = X^3-1 $ So $A^3 = 1$ And $P(A) = Q(A)$ with $Q = P \mod \chi_A$

This matrix is also circulant, and lots is known about them.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0 \end{bmatrix},
$$
we have :$A^3=I_3\implies (A^3)^k =(I_3)^k=I_3$
